# JSON string parse typescript

Tags: typescript

i want to parse this string in a JSON object

```
{'rinosinusite': "['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Prurito nasale', 'Prurito occhio', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Rinorrea nasale sieroso', 'Febbre']", 'rinite micotica': "['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Rinorrea nasale sieroso']", 'rinite medicamentosa': "['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di  Neutrophil: 0-1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Uso eccessivo di farmaci']", 'NARNE': "['Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']", 'rinite irritativa': "['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']", 'poliposi antrocoanale': "['Grado di Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']", 'condizione normale': "['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di  Neutrophil: 0-1']"}
```

but i get this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SergioPC\Desktop\rhinocyt\src\controllers\diagnosis.js:508:38)
at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

if i send the string above to the client it is displayed as

```
"{'rinosinusite': \"['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Prurito nasale', 'Prurito occhio', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Rinorrea nasale sieroso', 'Febbre']\", 'rinite micotica': \"['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Rinorrea nasale sieroso']\", 'rinite medicamentosa': \"['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di  Neutrophil: 0-1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra', 'Uso eccessivo di farmaci']\", 'NARNE': \"['Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']\", 'rinite irritativa': \"['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']\", 'poliposi antrocoanale': \"['Grado di Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di Neutrophil: 1', 'Ostruzione nasale sinistra']\", 'condizione normale': \"['Grado di  Eosinophil: 0', 'Grado di  Mastocyte: 0', 'Grado di  Neutrophil: 0-1']\"}\r\n"
```

i even tried to replace chars as "\n" but replace function doesn't seem to work for this..

Comment: json uses `"` instead of `'`

Comment: Could you make sure you have pasted the correct format of json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in JSON always use double quotes (") instead of single quotes ('). https://www.json.org/json-en.html
Also you should the remove the quotes around the array (`[]` instead of `"[]"`)

Your JSON should look like this:

```
{"rinosinusite": ["Grado di  Eosinophil: 0"]}
```